# GNU as doesn't accept flag when called from makefile, but OK when manually typed

Tags: gcc, makefile, 68hc12

I am trying to recover a project that I was forced to put on the back burner a few years ago when the M68HC12 was current.  I have $1000 invested in prototypes, so don't want to start over with a new chip since it is a proof of concept project.

Trying to download a copy of m6811-elf-gcc for new dev laptop is OK but binutils patches for the 68HC11 web site 404's and nowhere else to be found, so I just copied binaries from backup of prior dev laptop.

I am running SuSE linux LEAP 15.0. gcc 7.4.1 and as 2.31.1.20180828-lp150.5.3.

I kept getting 'as: unrecognized option '-m68hc12''  so  I copied m6811-elf-as from backup and put it in path.  I still get the same error from *as*.

Decoding the output of make, I can see it is calling the m6811 version of as:

make -n gives (in part)
...
m6811-elf-as -o mcx12.o -m68hc12 -mshort mcxif.s system.s mcx.s clkdrivr.s scidrv.s atddrivr.s main2mcx.s vectors.s 
...

but when I manually type in the exact same line that make is saying it generates, it works perfectly on the previously cc'ed source code without the 'as: unrecognized option '-m68hc12' ' error.

So make is saying that it is executing that line and gets errors, but the line itself does not when entered manually.

Any ideas?

any help very appreciated!

Nigel Johnson

update Oct 15:
I agree with what you say, but I cannot see how it can output m6811-elf-gcc with the -n option and really be calling as!

here is the output of make:

```
T430:/home/nigel/Project - RPT # make
m6811-elf-gcc -m68hc12 -mshort -g -O3 -fno-ident -fno-common -fomit-frame- 
pointer -mrelax -mlong-calls -msoft-reg-count=0 -Wall   -c -o main.o 
main.c
main.c:102: warning: return type defaults to `int'
main.c: In function `main':
main.c:133: warning: implicit declaration of function `atdinit'
main.c:149: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
as: unrecognized option '-m68hc12'
make: *** [<builtin>: main.o] Error 1
T430:/home/nigel/Project - RPT #
```

Here is make -n:

```
T430:/home/nigel/Project - RPT # make -n   
m6811-elf-gcc -m68hc12 -mshort -g -O3 -fno-ident -fno-common -fomit-frame-pointer -mrelax -mlong-calls -msoft-reg-count=0 -Wall   -c -o main.o main.c                                           
m6811-elf-gcc -m68hc12 -mshort -g -O3 -fno-ident -fno-common -fomit-frame-pointer -mrelax -mlong-calls -msoft-reg-count=0 -Wall   -c -o tasks.o tasks.c                                         
m6811-elf-gcc -m68hc12 -mshort -g -O3 -fno-ident -fno-common -fomit-frame-pointer -mrelax -mlong-calls -msoft-reg-count=0 -Wall   -c -o dtmf.o dtmf.c                                           
m6811-elf-ld -o mcx12.elf -mm68hc12elfb -defsym vectors_addr=0xff80 --relax -L/usr/lib/gcc-lib/m6811-elf/3.3.6-m68hc1x-20060122/m68hc12/mlong-calls/ 
crt0.o mcx12.o main.o tasks.o dtmf.o  -lgcc  
m6811-elf-objcopy  -O srec --srec-len=32 --change-section-lma .text+0xF0000 --change-section-lma .rodata+0xF0000 --change-section-lma .data+0xF0000 --change-section-lma .vectors+0xF0000 mcx12.elf mcx12.s19                                                                                                                                                                                   
m6811-elf-objdump  -S -D mcx12.elf>mcx12.dis                                                                                                                                                    
m6811-elf-size     mcx12.elf                                                                                                                                                                    
T430:/home/nigel/Project - RPT #
```

and my commands without erros for one small assembler file:

```
T430:/home/nigel/Project - RPT # m6811-elf-as crt0.s -m68hc12                                                                                                                                   
T430:/home/nigel/Project - RPT # m6811-elf-as crt0.s -m68hc12
```

Update 2019-10-18:

OK, added that to makefile, and now makefile says:

```
m6811-elf-gcc -v -m68hc12 -mshort -g -O3 -fno-ident -fno-common -fomit-frame-pointer -mrelax -mlong-calls -msoft-reg-count=0 -Wall   -c -o main.o main.c
m6811-elf-gcc -v -m68hc12 -mshort -g -O3 -fno-ident -fno-common -fomit-frame-pointer -mrelax -mlong-calls -msoft-reg-count=0 -Wall   -c -o tasks.o tasks.c
m6811-elf-gcc -v -m68hc12 -mshort -g -O3 -fno-ident -fno-common -fomit-frame-pointer -mrelax -mlong-calls -msoft-reg-count=0 -Wall   -c -o dtmf.o dtmf.c
m6811-elf-ld -o mcx12.elf -mm68hc12elfb -defsym vectors_addr=0xff80 --relax -L/usr/lib/gcc-lib/m6811-elf/3.3.6-m68hc1x-20060122/m68hc12/mlong-calls/ crt0.o mcx12.o main.o tasks.o dtmf.o  -lgcc
m6811-elf-objcopy  -O srec --srec-len=32 --change-section-lma .text+0xF0000 --change-section-lma .rodata+0xF0000 --change-section-lma .data+0xF0000 --change-section-lma .vectors+0xF0000 mcx12.elf mcx12.s19
m6811-elf-objdump  -S -D mcx12.elf>mcx12.dis
m6811-elf-size     mcx12.elf
T430:/home/nigel/Project - RPT #
```

BUT: output of make now says:

```
make
m6811-elf-gcc -v -m68hc12 -mshort -g -O3 -fno-ident -fno-common -fomit-frame-pointer -mrelax -mlong-calls -msoft-reg-count=0 -Wall   -c -o main.o main.c
Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc-lib/m6811-elf/3.3.6-m68hc1x-20060122/specs
Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc-lib/m6811-elf/specs
Configured with: ./configure --target=m6811-elf --program-prefix=m6811-elf- --enable-languages=c,c++,ada --prefix=/usr --host=i686-linux
Thread model: single
gcc version 3.3.6-m68hc1x-20060122 /usr/lib/gcc-lib/m6811-elf/3.3.6-m68hc1x-20060122/cc1 -quiet -v -D__GNUC__=3 -D__GNUC_MINOR__=3 -D__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__=6 -Dmc68hc1x -D__mc68hc1x__ -D__mc68hc1x -D__HAVE_SHORT_INT__ -D__INT__=16 -Dmc6812 -DMC6812 -Dmc68hc12 -D__USE_RTC__main.c -quiet -dumpbase main.c -m68hc12 -mshort -mrelax -mlong-    calls -msoft-reg-count=0 -auxbase-strip main.o -g -O3 -Wall -version -fno-dent -fno-common -fomit-frame-pointer -o /tmp/cc0exwc0.s
GNU C version 3.3.6-9s12x-20120502 (m68hc11-elf)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4).
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc-lib/m68hc11-elf/3.3.6-9s12x-20120502/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/m68hc11-elf/sys-include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here: /usr/m68hc11-elf/include
End of search list.
main.c:102: warning: return type defaults to `int'
main.c: In function `main':
main.c:133: warning: implicit declaration of function `atdinit'
main.c:149: warning: control reaches end of non-void function   
as -m68hc12 -mshort -mlong-double -o main.o /tmp/cc0exwc0.
as: unrecognized option '-m68hc12'
make: *** [<builtin>: main.o] Error 1  
T430:/home/nigel/Project - RPT #
```

I will explore those non-existent directories and see what happens if I copy them from backup :-)

Comment: Based on your error message I don't see how you can be running the same command as make.  If you were really running `m6811-elf-as -o ...` I would expect the error message you get to be prefixed with `m6811-elf-as: unrecognized option` not `as: unrecognized option`.  It's possible `m6811-elf-as` is a script of course.  Please edit your question and _cut and paste_ the exact make output that fails and the exact commands you're typing.  Please use StackOverflow's formatting capabilities to format these as code rather than text.

Comment: It seems that `m6811-elf-gcc` driver tries to call assembler through `as` instead of `m6811-elf-as`, which is probably a native assembler. Please call `m6811-elf-gcc` command exactly as written by make, but including a `-v`, like this: `m6811-elf-gcc -v -m68hc12 -mshort -g -O3 -fno-ident -fno-common -fomit-frame- 
pointer -mrelax -mlong-calls -msoft-reg-count=0 -Wall   -c -o main.o`. Then please edit your post and provide the exact output.